# ASP.NET MVC how to not make route for every action

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

Is this possible?

I'd had to clutter my route registrations with random actions that I need for specific reasons that don't need any custom constraints or anything.

I want to do something like Admin/Categories/{action} where action can be anything and the controller is CategoryController.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setup an Admin Area, then the categories controller in that area will be accessed via /admin/*controller*...

Areas, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "Admin/Categories/{action}",
   new { controller = "Category" });
```